# $f(x,y)= \frac{2}{3} \ \text {when} \ x>0,y>0, x+y<1 \\$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

A continuous random vector $(X,Y)$ has a joint probability density function 
\begin{align}
f(x,y) & = \frac{2}{3} \ \text {when} \ x>0,y>0, x+y<1 \\
& = \frac{4}{3} \ \text{when} \ x<1,y<1, x+y>1 \\
& = 0 \ \text{otherwise} 
\end{align}

I am finding it difficult to find the marginal distribution of $X$.
I have drawn the sample space, and it is a unit square with density $\frac{2}{3}$ below the diagonal and density $\frac{4}{3}$ above the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy = \int_{0}^{1-x} \frac{2}{3}dy + \int_{?}^{?} \cdots$$

Comment: will the answer be $f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{1} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy =\int_{0}^{1-x} \frac{2}{3} dy+ \int_{1-x}^{1} \frac{4}{3} dy$?

Comment: @AyanBiswas What else?